# Sharepoint 2016 User Profile Service syncronization only works after iisreset

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, farm-admin

We're testing a migration from **Sharepoint 2010** to **2016** (installed on WIndows Server 2012R2) and we managed to make it work and import all files from old one. We have 2 main problems:

1. Somehow our **farmadmin** account it's not recognized as **admin** account in **Central Administration** and for that it cannot be used to log in (we can only login with a personal account or with any other account but use http://localhost:xxx which only brings part of functionality) -  we tried every solution that could find on internet but with no luck.
2. Our **User Profile Service** not updating user info -> Ex: I have a user in an Active Directory group **Alpha** and I move it to group **Beta** -> I try *Incremental Synchronization* (no update) -> I try *Full Sync* (again no update) he still can see files from old group and not the new one - only way to see changes is to do an **iisreset** (or wait for a few hours when something happens and it updates) -> ***Is this a normal behavior? Because in SP2010 changes could be seen in a matter of minutes or less.***

**UPDATE** - I managed to make sync(second issue) work by doing [THIS](https://www.andrewjbillings.com/sharepoint-2013-claims-authentication-ad-group-changes-not-reflected/)

```
$sts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$sts.FormsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 2)
$sts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 2)
$sts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan -minutes 1)
$sts.Update()
iisreset /noforce
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first issue:

Whether the Farm Admin account is added to farm administrators group in CA->Security->Manage the farm administrators group?

If so, try to troubleshoot your issue as below:

1. Switch other farm account to check if the same issue will occur.
2. Remove and re-add the problematical farm account in the farm administrators group.
3. [Clear SharePoint configuration cache](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/clearing-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache/)
4. Re-run the SharePoint 2016 configuration wizard.
5. Run SharePoint Central Administration as administrator and check again.
6. Go to CA site settings->Site permissions->check if the farm account have full control, and check if there is Farm Administrators group in it.

Comment: Unbelievable, we've tried, except 3, all of the above - it turns out that clear configuration cache + re-run configuration wizard did the job. We've struggling with this for a month. Thank you so  much!!